# Implement a custom Container Provider for Jersey

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, containers, handler, netty

I want to implement a custom Container Provider for running Jersey with Netty 4.

I started checking the code on how it's implemented with Grizzly 2 HTTP codec, but the code is not really commented other than some plain Javadocs which are not helpful at all.

What do I need to implement so I can use my Netty HTTP request and pass it to Jersey so it understands it, and then obtain the Jersey response and render it out through a Netty HTTP response?

From what I understand so far, I have to create classes that implement:  org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ContainerProvider, org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.Container and org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ContainerLifecycleListener to be able to startup and shutdown Jersey inside my Netty server (a Jersey Handler), but there is no documentation whatsoever on them.

Then, I have to implement: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException, org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest and org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse to somehow pass the request and response to/from Jersey. Then to write out the response I have to implement a org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ContainerResponseWriter.

That's what I have so far, but I have no idea on how to implement them or put them together somehow, and also how would I enable async (I'm guessing through Netty's NIO, but still no clue on how Jersey does request/response) or CDI?

Any help or documentation I can get would be great, from a 10,000ft view of an implementation container flow to tips and tricks and special documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Why not start by implementing the jax rs spec in netty ? It's very well documented at https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/index.html

Comment: @Nicholas the question is not where the JAX-RS spec is (I'm actually contributing to the JSR) or how to implement it, is about Jersey containers which has nothing to do with the spec, it's implementation specific, thanks

Comment: Did you make any progress with this @RaulG? We want to use Netty with Jersey but don't have confidence in the bundled implementation (we've already found a few serious bugs).